# How to include a module from a different file in Fortran 95?

Tags: fortran, fortran95, silverfrost-fortran

The question is obvious I think, although I googled it, I could not find any solutions. I want to split my source code to keep it more maintainable. How can I reference a module in another file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the `use` statement.  You might, for example, have one source file containing the definition of a module, outline:

```
module abstract_types
    implicit none
    ! declarations
  contains
    ! procedure definitions
end module abstract_types
```

and then, in another source file, a program which uses the module, outline:

```
program hello_there
    use abstract_types
    implicit none
    ! declarations
    ! executable statements
end program hello_there
```

Note:

- Any `use` statements precede the `implicit` statement.
- The `use` statement refers to the module by name.

When it comes to compilation, make sure that you compile the module source file before the program source file; at compilation time (not at link time) the compiler will look for a module file (often called a `mod` file) to satisfy the reference to the module in the `use` statement.  The `mod` file is a bit like a header file, but it's created by the compiler.

Later, when you link your program you'll need the object files for both module and program.

Comment: @ High Performance Mar: How could you indicate the compiler where the mod files are located?